# ObjectDataSource: needs to 'show all records' on demand instead of paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource, custompaging

I have a GridView and ObjectDataSource set up to do custom paging and everything was fine. Now the client wants a 'show all' button. In the event handler for this button, what can I do to achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want show all records on a button click, then its better to set `AllowPaging = false` on the button's Click handler. It will simply disable the paging feature and bind all the records to the gridview:

```
Gridview1.AllowPaging = false;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Since the OjbectDataSource uses custom paging I had to also set the number of rows to take as the number that exist via a query, but your answer certainly got me past the hard part. Thanks for the help.